# Why I cannot use += to Vector2?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Why I cannot use += to Vector2? I can only use *=. Why is tahat?
I cannot use this:

```
Vector2 v2;
v2 += 10;
```

I'm getting information, that I cannot use "+=" to "Vector2" or "int".

Comment: What do you expect the latter operation to do? Vector-scalar addition is generally not defined, while vector-scalar multiplication is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector is just that, a vector. An int is called a scalar value. You could think of the vector being 2D and the int being 1D.

When times-ing a vector by an int (or float) it goes through and times each part of the vector with the int.
Now if you try and add this int, well what can it do? You've got an x and y value in the vector and you're trying to add a value that doesn't have a direction.

You can look up all sorts of vector maths on your own.

Just an extra bit, were you perhaps looking for `v2.x += 10;`?

Comment: I wanted use it for code: rb.MovePosition(v2 + speed * Time.deltaTime);
rb is Rigidbody2D rb; and the problem is that I cannot add speed and Time to v2.

Comment: Typically, people normalise the input vector and just times it by speed and time. `v2 * speed * Time.deltaTime`

Comment: But it doesn't work when I want to move my character/object. I know, that I can use:rb.MovePosition(rb.position  + v2 * speed * Time.deltaTime);. But I was curious, if I can use it with, just Vector2.

Comment: v2 should be a form of input. If you really want to do it the way you have use the last note on my answer and add to just the x or y.